# How to know how many users for my app ? android

Tags: android

My app currently does not need any registration for users to use. I am using Firebase for push notification but is there a way to check the list of firebase's registrationID for each user from the firebase console ? What is the standard practice to get the exact amount number of app installs ? Is it possible to check from firebase console ?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/?gclid=CIfRxfHIsdICFYWWvQodgN0N5g

Answer (score 0):

- You will need to setup anonymous login in your code to track guest
  users.
- You can also setup analytics to pull data into your
  database.https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/?gclid=CIfRxfHIsdICFYWWvQodgN0N5g
- You will also get the line chart for realtime connection count from
  Database - Usage